# How to get top n prediction labels from classifier.predict_proba() output?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I am trying to get top n predicted labels of a text based multi-label classification problem as a list for a particular record.

I have tried the following...

```
y_pred_proba = classifier.predict_proba(X_test) 
n = 5
top_n_pred = np.argsort(y_pred_proba, axis=1)[:,-n :]
class_labels = classifier.classes_
```

Please help me to combine `top_n_pred` and `class_labels` to get top n labels as a list for each row of `X_test`?

If there is any shortcut to achieve the same, that is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first try `class_labels[top_n_pred]` which might fail but then just do it with an iterator.

Comment: class_labels[top_n_pred] works and It gives the corresponding class labels of top n predictions.